# How to loop through objects of a lua class

Tags: oop, lua

local card = {x, y, w, h};

```
    function card:new(o, x, y, w, h)
        local o = o or {};
        setmetatable(o, self);
        self.__index = self;
        self.x = x;
        self.y = y;
        self.w = w;
        self.h = h;
        return o;
    end
```

How do i loop through objects created by this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this, unless you add some structure to explicitly track created objects in a table somewhere (probably with "weak" keys to allow them to be garbage collected).

It *may* be possible to traverse all local and global values to find tables that have `__index` value pointing to that `card` table, but it's unlikely to be practical.

Comment: I've added a new table called objects and I insert each object in it when created. Thought there would be a more direct way to do it, doesn't seem like it though. Thank you either way.

Comment: @ALw7sH "more direct way": Anything you call "class" is indirect because Lua doesn't have a class mechanism except what you make from tables and metamethods. But then again, I don't know of any language that gives you this.